# Metal turned dull grey in dishwasher?

Tags: safety, dishwasher, metal

I put a shiny coffee filter holder in dishwasher, and it turned dull grey. In the pic you can see the difference with filter cup, which retained silvery shine in the same dishwasher:

[image: filter cup and holder]

The holder leaves dark grey spots on kitchen towel, when I try to brush it.

I thought it is aluminum, but got confused by posts in internet stating it would turn black if washed in dishwasher. Mine is dull silvery grey.

**What would the filter holder be made of, and is it safe to use it now, considering all the coffee drips through it into the cup?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's cast aluminum.

Most dishwasher detergents contain lye (NaOH, sodium hydroxide) - which reacts drastically with aluminum. Fortunately the dwell time in a dishwasher is short enough that it generally only darkens, as opposed to dissolving entirely (which it will do with adequate time.)

Yes, it's safe to use (after hand-washing and rinsing throughly), no, it's not dishwasher-safe and should be hand-washed instead.

The filter cup is of some different metal (either stainless steel or something nickle-plated, at a guess.)

Answer (score 0):

That looks like Aluminum and such items should not be washed in an automatic dishwasher.  Here is an article that discusses the problem:

[Aluminum and Dishwashers](https://ask.extension.org/questions/161186)

Their recommendation for cleaning is:

> When washed in a dishwasher, aluminum cookware can react and darken
>   due to mineral content in the water, chemicals in the detergent or
>   high heat from the dryer. Natural products such as lemon juice,
>   vinegar or cream of tartar remove discoloration and provide fast,
>   effective results without damaging the metal.

Comment: (The link is broken)